# Typo in welcome banner

Tags: bug, status-completed

The welcome banner says

> Welcome to Q&A site for Ubuntu users and developers

image:

[image]

It should probably say

> Welcome to the Q&A site for Ubuntu users and developers

or,

> Welcome to Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed according to your second suggestion. It now reads:

> Welcome to Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers — check out the
>   [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq)

[image: Welcome to Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers — check out the FAQ]